# getting more records than expected with simple query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these query:

```
select b.type,b.name,a.name_b,a.start_time
         from runinfo a left JOIN definition b
                        on a.sched_table=b.parent_table
                        and a.name_b=b.name
                        where sched_table not like 'PLAN' 
         and to_char(start_time,'YYYYMMDD') = to_char(current_date-1,'YYYYMMDD')
         order by start_time desc;
```

Tables are:

```
DEFINITION
----------

TYPE: COMMAND
NAME: DAVE
.........

RUNINFO
-------

START_TIME: 2019/08/15 23:59
NAME_B: DAVE
.........
START_TIME: 2019/08/15 23:58
NAME_B: DAVE
........
```

I get duplicate rows and I can't understand:

```
TYPE     NAME   START_TIME           NAME_B
COMMAND  DAVE   2019/08/15 23:59     DAVE
COMMAND  DAVE   2019/08/15 23:59     DAVE
COMMAND  DAVE   2019/08/15 23:58     DAVE
COMMAND  DAVE   2019/08/15 23:58     DAVE
```

Why I get two rows of every record?

thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: Joining a table with one record to a table with two records gives a result set with at most two records, period (even for a cross join).  I speculate that your starting tables already have duplicate data.

Comment: But I would like to extract the results of table runfinfo, add the column type of the other table. Is possible to make that? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `select distinct` to handle the symptom, but your underlying tables would seem to have duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need an `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN` -

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.type,b.name,a.name_b,a.start_time
FROM runinfo a
INNER JOIN definition b ON a.sched_table=b.parent_table
                       AND a.name_b=b.name
WHERE sched_table NOT LIKE '%PLAN%' 
AND TO_CHAR(start_time,'YYYYMMDD') = TO_CHAR(current_date-1,'YYYYMMDD')
ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

Also I have updated your Like predicate.

Comment: There must be some duplicates in your underlying tables. I have added DISTINCT clause. This might solve your problem.